# How to close a question and accept an answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

First of all this is not the programming question. And please pardon me for this question. I am just 10 days old on stack overlow. This is a great learning portal.

My profile shows 0 % accept rate, probably I am not accepting any answers. But there is no
option to do this. Where to find this option?

I want to close my answered question. Is there any option for this and if yes then where is it?

Comment: Click the green check mark next to the answer that you want to accept. It's great that you notice the accept rate - far too many new users don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when someone answers your question then there is a disabled tick mark just below rating column, if you check that tick mark, that will consider that you have accepted that answer.

and I am not sure about how to close a question but I think it is one of the privileges you get when you gather sufficient points for that privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the hollow check (tick mark) sign below the voting arrows on the left side of the answer that you would like to accept. From now on please post such questions on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Each answer has a tick next to it, if you mouse over it it says "Click t oset this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle."